# Check validation rules in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-events

I'm new to Yii framework so I'm trying to understand the way it is working.
I have the following validation rules for a user creating form, now what I need is to check in afterValidation() method, if all the validation rules have passed an the hash the user password. What I don't know is, if Yii has a build-in method that returns true or false if the validation rules have passed or not.

```
 public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('email, password, username', 'required'),
            array('email, username, password', 'length', 'max'=>256),
            array('email, username', 'unique'),
            array('password', 'compare'),
            array('password_repeat', 'safe'),
        );
    }




 protected function afterValidate()
        {
            parent::afterValidate();
          if("VALIDATION RULES HAVE PASSED, ther is no error message")
{  
            $this->password = $this->encrypt($this->password);
}
        }
        public function encrypt($value)
        {
          return md5($value);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Or Google? It's really easy to find.

Comment: If I am asking my question here, it means that I have checked the documentation and not only I have also check on Google! smartass

Comment: Because `$model->validate()` was so hard to find, [right?](https://www.google.com/search?q=yii+how+to+validate+model&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) A little effort can go a long way.

Comment: Trickery I have already tried but when I call that function  I get this error: Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\php\Yii\framework\web\auth\CWebUser.php on line 559    Maybe I'm not using $model->validate() in the right way, any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you should be using is [$this->hasErrors()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#hasErrors-detail) since your form validation has already been performed. The likely reason for the nesting error is due to it calling your `afterValidate()` after each `$this->validate()` since I would think this is called automatically if validation is performed and you just end up with an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead if putting anything in `afterValidate()`, which gets run in a validation cycle, I think you want to put your code in `beforeSave()`.

`beforeSave()` will only be run if your validation rules run and don't have errors.

As a bonus: if you are just doing standard password stuff, consider using the [Yii Password behavior](https://github.com/phpnode/YiiPassword). It will save you lots of time and has already been thoroughly checked by some of the best Yii programmers out there.